# Compare and Calculate with numeric generic Type T

Tags: c#, generics, types, operators

I have the following C# code:

```
T convert(T numericInput)
{
  int threshold = 2;
  double factor = 0.5;
  if(numericInput > threshold)
  {
    numericInput *= factor;
  }
  return numericInput;
}
```

When implementing this I got the error `CS0019 Operator '*=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'T' and 'double'`. I get the same error for als operators.
How can I fix this? Can I use the ICompareable interface to specify T?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: If you use .NET 6 or newer, have a look at [generic math](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/math).

Comment: It is not very clear what you are actually asking about. You cannot really  do *anything* with a generic object, other than store it, if you do not have any generic constraints. And even if you constrain your type using the generic math interfaces you are still limited with regards to constants. You cannot just take any arbitrary numeric type and compare it to a int or multiply it with a double.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the generic INumber interface and create generic instances for your constants.

```
static T Convert<T>(T numericInput) where T: INumber<T>
{
  T threshold = T.CreateChecked(2);
  T factor = T.CreateChecked(0.5);
  if (numericInput > threshold)
  {
    numericInput *= factor;
  }
  return numericInput;
}
```

This fiddle shows how this works with different numeric types.
https://dotnetfiddle.net/vsiURW